# Какие требования предъявляются к volatile переменным

Tags: java

На собеседовании был задан вопрос: "Какие требования предъявляются к volatile переменным?". Т.е. зачем это все нужно и что дает понятно, а вот по поводу требований я не смог найти конкретного ответа.

Comment: Может это и имелось ввиду? Т.е. возможно в данном контексте это означает, что если вы помечаете переменную как volatile, то это значит.... и использовать её надо для того чтобы ....

Comment: Ну если смотреть в [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) то `volatile` могут быть только поля, не отмеченные, как `final`. В других случаях, и смысла, в общем, нет - локальные переменные не разделяются между потоками, а `final` поля не меняются.

Comment: @zRrr, volatile обеспечивает (в том числе) запрет переупорядочивания операций процессором. Очень хотелось сказать, что из этого следует, что для локальных переменных он тоже может понадобиться, но пример придумать не удалось... Но у джавы как раз есть жизнь на сомнительных архитектурах процессоров :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, как мне кажется, в случае одного потока, jvm должна сгенерировать инструкции, видимый результат выполнения которых должен соответствовать описанному в jls (там прописан порядок выполнения, вычисления аргументов и т.п.), т.е. программист не должен этим заморачиваться. В случае нескольких потоков, чтобы `volatile` гарантировано давал эффект, [должна быть пара](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#wishful-unobserved-volatiles) volatile write -> volatile read. Вообще, барьеры в java можно использовать через Unsafe/VarHandles в JDK 9.

Answer (score 2):

Если 2 потока читают и пишут в переменную, то использование только `volatile` недостаточно. Необходимо ещё использовать синхронизацию, чтобы гарантировать атомарность чтения и записи. Ещё из-за `volatile` страдает перформанс, потому что значение пишется\читается сразу в память, минуя кэши, а это дорого стоит. То есть не стоит использовать `volatile` в местах, где важен перформанс.